# Can't install Python 3.5 files for Zipline

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, zipline

I'm trying to install Zipline and all of its dependencies using conda for Python 3.5. However, I'm only getting the 2.7 versions of the files:

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    logbook-0.12.5             |           py27_0         111 KB  quantopian
    zipline-0.7.0              |       np18py27_0         241 KB  quantopian
    ta-lib-0.4.8               |       np18py27_0         6.3 MB  quantopian
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         6.7 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    asn1crypto:                    0.24.0-py27_0
    backports:                     1.0-py27_1
    backports.functools_lru_cache: 1.5-py27_1
    backports_abc:                 0.5-py27h6d9a788_0
    ca-certificates:               2018.12.5-0
    cffi:                          1.11.5-py27hc64555f_1
    chardet:                       3.0.4-py27_1
    cryptography:                  2.4.2-py27hc64555f_0
    cycler:                        0.10.0-py27h0308610_0
    dateutil:                      2.4.1-py27_0
    enum34:                        1.1.6-py27_1
    freetype:                      2.9.1-h4d385ea_1
    functools32:                   3.2.3.2-py27_1
    futures:                       3.2.0-py27_0
    icu:                           58.2-hb13015a_1
    idna:                          2.8-py27_0
    ipaddress:                     1.0.22-py27_0
    jpeg:                          9b-hb117b5b_2
    kiwisolver:                    1.0.1-py27hc56fc5f_0
    libpng:                        1.6.36-h7a46e7a_0
    logbook:                       0.12.5-py27_0           quantopian
    matplotlib:                    2.2.3-py27h263d877_0
    numpy:                         1.8.2-py27_0
    openssl:                       1.0.2p-h0c8e037_0
    pandas:                        0.14.1-np18py27_0
    pycparser:                     2.19-py27_0
    pyopenssl:                     18.0.0-py27_0
    pyparsing:                     2.3.1-py27_0
    pyqt:                          5.6.0-py27hc56fc5f_6
    pysocks:                       1.6.8-py27_0
    python-dateutil:               2.7.5-py27_0
    pytz:                          2018.9-py27_0
    qt:                            5.6.2-vc9he136c73_12
    requests:                      2.21.0-py27_0
    scipy:                         0.14.0-np18py27_0
    singledispatch:                3.4.0.3-py27h18657b7_0
    sip:                           4.18.1-py27hc56fc5f_2
    six:                           1.12.0-py27_0
    sqlite:                        3.26.0-h0c8e037_0
    ta-lib:                        0.4.8-np18py27_0        quantopian
    tornado:                       5.1.1-py27h0c8e037_0
    urllib3:                       1.24.1-py27_0
    vs2008_runtime:                9.00.30729.1-hfaea7d5_1
    win_inet_pton:                 1.0.1-py27_1
    zipline:                       0.7.0-np18py27_0        quantopian
    zlib:                          1.2.11-h3cc03e0_3

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    certifi:                       2018.8.24-py35_1                   --> 2018.11.29-py27_0
    pip:                           10.0.1-py35_0                      --> 18.1-py27_0
    setuptools:                    40.2.0-py35_0                      --> 40.6.3-py27_0
    wheel:                         0.31.1-py35_0                      --> 0.32.3-py27_0
    wincertstore:                  0.2-py35h3d52121_0                 --> 0.2-py27h87a2792_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    python:                        3.5.6-he025d50_0                   --> 2.7.15-hcb6e200_5
    vc:                            14.1-h0510ff6_4                    --> 9-h7299396_1

Proceed ([y]/n)? n
```

I can see that Python 3.5 files are [available on Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/Quantopian/zipline/files). How do I specify that I want the Python 3.5 files, not the 2.7 ones?

I ran the following commands from the Anaconda prompt:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5
conda activate py35
conda install -c Quantopian zipline
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. I quitted the zipline installation process and installed some other packages instead. Then I tried to install zipline again, and conda did not asked to downgrade python anymore. So I guess it is just some automatic environment solving mechanism with conda. You can try install zipline first, then upgrade python back to 3.5 again.